WalletSendTransactionError: Non-base58 character
I am facing issue with the minting of the NFT.
This is the code inside my react component.
const { connection } = useConnection();
const { publicKey, sendTransaction } = useWalletSol();
const mintEntryPass = async () => {
    try {
      // await connect();
      setLoading(true);
      const provider = new anchor.AnchorProvider(connection, window.solana)
      const program = new Program(
        idl,
        new PublicKey("3TvJwdpsqUH7DpdGCP46nSd4tHc1nLzcyA1V7jZ9aUg4"),
        provider.publicKey
      );
      anchor.setProvider(provider);

      
      const key = provider.publicKey;
      const associatedTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
        connection,
        key,
        new PublicKey("59nZSchpUxETCDYnHL6WTjPi9DCaQ1ACu6UDxHF1Qs1T"),
        key,
        false
      );
      console.log(associatedTokenAccount, provider);

      const lamports = 1000000000;

      const transaction = new Transaction().add(
        SystemProgram.transfer({
          fromPubkey: publicKey,
          toPubkey: new PublicKey(
            "D71iNpYiwyGHFWWCKffa1krCWQPCmvfZ7hGthbULvq8j"
          ),
          lamports,
        })
      );

      //Pay to mint

      // const {
      //   context: { slot: minContextSlot },
      //   value: { blockhash, lastValidBlockHeight },
      // } = await connection.getLatestBlockhashAndContext();

      // const signature = await sendTransaction(transaction, connection, {
      //   minContextSlot,
      // });

      // await connection.confirmTransaction({
      //   blockhash,
      //   lastValidBlockHeight,
      //   signature,
      // });

      // console.log(signature);

      const mint_tx = new Transaction().add(
        
        // Create the ATA account that is associated with our mint on our anchor wallet
        createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
          key,
          associatedTokenAccount,
          key,
          new PublicKey("59nZSchpUxETCDYnHL6WTjPi9DCaQ1ACu6UDxHF1Qs1T")
        )
      );

      console.log(mint_tx);
      // sends and create the transaction
      const res = await sendTransaction(mint_tx, connection);

      // Executes our code to mint our token into our specified ATA
      await program.methods
        .mintNft(
          {
            accounts: {
              mintAuthority: new PublicKey(
                "2kuy9DSkDUY5Lm4rnsunZTL89bs1Jb5Cr1enS2iyKkGe"
              ),
              mint: new PublicKey(
                "59nZSchpUxETCDYnHL6WTjPi9DCaQ1ACu6UDxHF1Qs1T"
              ),
              tokenProgram: new PublicKey(
                "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA"
              ),
              metadata: new PublicKey(
                "FNJrB44fgi3rRDgUSqNop3dyujAX2oyVc7uHgXbX1aWb"
              ),
              tokenAccount: associatedTokenAccount,
              tokenMetadataProgram: new PublicKey(
                "metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s"
              ),
              payer: key,
              systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
              rent: web3.SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
            },
          },
          new PublicKey("2kuy9DSkDUY5Lm4rnsunZTL89bs1Jb5Cr1enS2iyKkGe"),
          "https://arweave.net/URI",
          "Omen"
        )
        .rpc();

      // Get minted token amount on the ATA for our anchor wallet
      const minted = (
        await program.provider.connection.getParsedAccountInfo(
          associatedTokenAccount
        )
      ).value.data.parsed.info.tokenAmount.amount;

      console.log(minted);

      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };


The error on the console says-
 WalletSendTransactionError: Non-base58 character
    at StandardWalletAdapter.sendTransaction (adapter.ts:347:1)
    at async WalletProviderBase.tsx:202:1
    at async mintEntryPass (Solana.jsx:205:1) 


Could you edit this question to give actual addresses where you have eg new PublicKey("<Minting Contract>")? The issue is probably a bad address (Solana addresses are base58 encoded), but since you've removed them all it's impossible to give a more useful pointer than that!

@CallumM I have updated the question, now can you please help with the issue?
